# Failed to perform datatable search

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I am currently using the datatables plugin to dynamically list table data I have made for a system I am working on.

Currently I have read enough of the plugin and I have not had many problems to use it, but today I have encountered a big problem. Having a datatable to list people by a specific type, everything works very well, shows me the information by the type that I am indicating (a single person in this case), but what is my surprise that when doing a search , By placing the letter "M", the datatable automatically finds ALL what is inside the table people that begins or contains the letter M. I have searched but I can not find how to keep that limitation that I have to show the information So that it also stays in the search.

The code I have of the following way to show the information and to carry out the search:

```
//Ordenacion
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumnas[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                ".$_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }

    //Filtracion
    $sWhere = " WHERE  s.id_tipo = 1";
    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch']."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    // Filtrado de columna individual 
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch_'.$i]."%'";
        }
    }


    //Obtener datos para mostrar SQL queries

    $sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumnas))."
    FROM personas p
    INNER JOIN sesion s ON s.personas_cedula=p.cedula 
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
    ";

    $rResult = $mysqli->query($sQuery);


    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = $mysqli->query($sQuery);
    $aResultFilterTotal = $rResultFilterTotal->fetch_array();
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
    SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
    FROM   $sTabla
    ";
    $rResultTotal = $mysqli->query($sQuery);
    $aResultTotal = $rResultTotal->fetch_array();
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];
```

I am a bit worried about the search situation because no other data should be shown. Maybe it's something silly what's happening, but I really can not solve it, that's why I'm looking for help.

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: **First of all your code is vulnerable to SQL injection** 

Datatable send a parameter that contains the search string in it, which is `sSearch`, you can use this parameter with all the column ion which you want to allow the searching.

Comment: But that could put in the sSearch so that in the search only it does it according to the sWhere parameter ??

Answer (score 0):

Putting the SQL Injection risk to one side for now, the reason you're not getting the correct results when filtering on `Person Type` and  using `M` as search term is this:

```
$sWhere = " WHERE  s.id_tipo = 1";
```

You have declared the PersonType filter argument, but then you check for a value in the search string:

```
if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
```

And then you **overwrite** the `sWhere` variable, so you're now not filtering on PersonType at all:

```
$sWhere = "WHERE (";
```

What you need to do is this:

```
$sWhere .=  " AND (";
```

I'm not familiar with PHP but I'm assuming the `.=` is the same as `+=`, ie `$sWhere = $sWhere +`

Comment: hello @markpsmith When placing the .= AND I get this error in datatables when doing a search: DataTables warning: table id=mitabla - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1 <--- This error comes out when there is something that is not well written or this is in the datatable code. If I put only the AND, although I have a single person type 1, to write another name I find it because they exist in the database of people...

Comment: You will have to debug the query to make sure there are no typos in it after all that string concatenation.